# Use content filter on the post that is password-protected

Tags: plugin-development, password

I’m trying to change content that is on the password-protected post from the plugin. 
When using `content` filter it seems not to work (redirect to wp-login.php gives the blank screen). Is there more appropriate filter for this?

My current code:

```
function change_client_post_type($content) {
     if(post_password_required()):
        $content = get_the_password_form();
     else: 
        ...content
     endif;

     return $content;
 }
```

Comment: is this your actual code?  with an ellipsis?  did you check your error log?

Comment: @rudtek No, there is actual loop which I’m not posting for brevity

Comment: Can't trouble shoot without details.  What about the log?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to return $content, not the form.

```
function change_client_post_type($content) {
 if(post_password_required()):
    return $content; //solution
 else: 
    ...content
 endif;

 return $content;
```

}